# What is the best way to save a file reference in Baqend?

Tags: ionic2, baqend

I'm building an Ionic 2 app, which uploads a profile image to Baqend:

```js
import { db } from 'baqend';
const img = new db.File({ folder: '/profiles',  data: imageData, type: 'base64', mimeType: 'image/jpeg' });
img.upload();
```

I can't find any type for a file reference. Whats the best way to save it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file reference type is currently not supported by Baqend, but it's planed. 
Currently, the best way is to save the id of the file and create a file object from it when loading:

Save:

```
img.upload().then(() => {
  let profile = new db.Profile();
  profile.img = img.id
  return profile.save();
});
```

Load:

```
db.Profile.load('profileId').then(profile => {
  let image = new db.File(profile.img);
  console.log(image.url);
});
```

This is much better than simply saving the path of the file because with `image.url` the SDK handles the cache invalidation. This way you could simply assign `image.url` as `src` to an image element.